# How to have Heroku Dyno run and then shut down after running once

Tags: python, heroku, scheduler

I have a python script that I want to run just once week automatically. It access data from a Heroku database in a private space, so I thought building a Heroku app and then using the [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) add-on would fulfill my needs. In any case, I need to run a Heroku dyno to access the data -- I can't otherwise.

However, looking at the App logs (using [Papertrail](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/papertrail)) I noticed that the app continues to repeatedly run the python script even after a successful iteration (`Process exited with status 0`). I *don't* want this to happen, since it probably puts unnecessary strain to the database.

Is there a way to run a script/app on Heroku and then actually shut it down until the next time it's explicitly called?

Answer (score 0):

Scheduler is probably the best way to do it, scheduler runs the configured tasks as a one off process and when it completes the process is terminated. However, if you only want it to run weekly you'd need to do some logic in your script to check if the day is the day you want the job to run on and if so proceed else just finish.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to remove the (`worker`) command running my script from the `Procfile` *and then* set up scheduler as [described here by Heroku.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler#installing-the-add-on)

If a command is in your `Procfile` it will continue to execute regardless of success status.